# windows store submission issue

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps, windows-store

When i am submitted my app to store i am getting following error from windows store after the splash screen launch:

Locations: MMRevamp_2016_1.1.0.0_x86_x64_arm.appxbundle
Tested OSes: Windows.Universal

Notes To Developer:
The app silently terminates at launch.

Steps to Reproduce:
1. Launch the app.
2. Notice that the app silently terminates at launch.

Tip: A Windows app may run flawlessly during development and testing, but after submitting it for certification testing, the app may crash or perform unexpectedly. Along these same lines, your app may not perform as expected after publication. This resource, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2859130, explains the most common reasons for this along with remedies.

I am developing windows 10 universal app and i have submitted release mode build and with successful windows app certification process.
What needs to do for this type of issue?
Any help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the tip from Store, I think that maybe the device the tester use is different from yours or there can be some setting missing on the tester’s device.

Also, if your app provides the service that need username/password to log in, you might need to give a testing pair for certification.

I would like to suggest you to provide a hosted video of the app’s functionality working properly in the [notes for certification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/notes-for-certification) when you resubmit your app. You could demonstrate how to test your app properly so that the tester can see your app perform well and know how to test it properly.
[image]

If you still cannot pass certification, you might try sending email to reportapp@microsoft.com with your publisher name and application id to have a closer look at your app with the assistance of that team.

Comment: even if i include notes, how will my issue with the crash at the splash screen resolve?

Comment: You might need to figure out the reason for the crash that can be the device type or some setting missing. Thus I think you should make communication with the tester first.